# How to mask a string inside tags, within a string?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have the below string (which was originally XML):

```
<Message><ProcedureName>TestUpdate</ProcedureName><Parameters><![CDATA[N'Yes',N'No']]></Parameters><MessageType>A</MessageType></Message>
```

I have tried the below but the text 'No' is dynamic (it can be a different value):

```
message.Replace("No", "********");
```

I'm not sure whether I can do this using `string.Replace`, *Regex* or a mix of both?

Comment: These appear to be parameter lists fed to a T-SQL command. If that is the case, be aware that the value might itself contain escaped single quotes (`N'He said ''Yes''.'`) and your replacement logic has to take that into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have settled on. It is not perfect but it satisfies my requirement.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(message, @"CDATA\[.*\]");
if (match.Success)
{
    maskedMessage = message.Replace(match.Value, "********");
}
```

Comment: This replaces the entirety of what's in `<Parameters>` -- well, almost, it leaves invalid markup. If you want to wipe the whole element instead of strings within it, you're much better off processing this string as actual XML (`m = XElement.Parse(...); m.Element("Parameters").Value = "*****";`). That `CDATA` happens to be used in `Parameters`, and only there, is arguably not something you should be relying on.

Comment: The XML has already been sent into a T-SQL command before I reach this code. This code is solely for the purpose of adding a log entry to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to get string between 2 tags before replacing:

```
 string str = "<Message><ProcedureName>TestUpdate</ProcedureName><Parameters><![CDATA[N'Yes',N'No']]></Parameters><MessageType>A</MessageType></Message>";
 Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"CDATA\[.*\]");
 if (match.Success)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(str_out);//"CDATA[N'Yes', N'No']]"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by 'dynamic' you mean it could be anything, including 'No', here's my attempt:

```
var source = "<Message><ProcedureName>TestUpdate</ProcedureName><Parameters><![CDATA[N'Yes',N'No']]></Parameters><MessageType>A</MessageType></Message>";
var regexstr = @"(.*\[CDATA\[.*,N')(.*)('\]\].*)";

var regex = new Regex(regexstr);
var matches = regex.Match(source);
Console.WriteLine($"{matches.Groups[1].Value}****{matches.Groups[3].Value}");

//Console Output: <Message><ProcedureName>TestUpdate</ProcedureName><Parameters><![CDATA[N'Yes',N'****']]></Parameters><MessageType>A</MessageType></Message>
```

This could possibly be optimised further but that is dependent on your source. Hope it helps!